# NSTableView Change cell color when selected

Tags: macos, nstableview

This is a **macOS** question

In

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?
```

I'm using

```
 func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {


    cell.layer?.backgroundColor = mintGreen.cgColor
```

to change the cell color.

Is it possible to change the color when the cell is selected?

Thanks

Comment: Selected in a selected row or a focused text field?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've updated the question

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29474301/43615 - that seems to work for me, as I get a drawRect call in the NSTableViewRow subclass every time its selection changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Realise this is an old question now, but I couldn't find a solution to this problem documented anywhere, so this is what I've come up with:

This code assumes an NSTableView with one column and therefore that the cell you are interested is in the zero indexed column. It also assumes a reference to the NSTableView on the delegate of 'theTableView'.

```
func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {

    // You'd probably want to handle this else statement more elegantly
    guard let selected = theTableView?.selectedRow else { return }

    if (selected != -1) {

        if let numberOfRows = theTableView?.numberOfRows {

            let sequenceOfRows = 0..<numberOfRows

            for row in sequenceOfRows.reversed() {

                if row == selected {

                    if let cell = theTableView?.view(atColumn: 0, row: selected, makeIfNecessary: false) {
                        cell.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.green.cgColor
                    }

                } else {

                    if let cell = theTableView?.view(atColumn: 0, row: Int(row), makeIfNecessary: false) {
                        cell.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear.cgColor
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    } else {

        // No row is selected, so iterate over all and revert background to .clear

        if let numberOfRows = theTableView?.numberOfRows {

            let sequenceOfRows = 0..<numberOfRows

            for row in sequenceOfRows {

                if let cell = theTableView?.view(atColumn: 0, row: Int(row), makeIfNecessary: false) {
                    cell.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear.cgColor
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works, and technically answers the question, but feels really horrible, having to iterate over all the rows to assess which background colour to change, and to change all the rows back again when the row selection changes or the row is deselected. I can't help feel there must be many more elegant or efficient ways to do this, but as I say can't find any documented myself.

Would be grateful if anyone else could update if there is another more succinct way of doing this, or if there is another pattern aside from the NSTableView delegates to achieve this.

Comment: I never did solve the issue, so thanks for the fix! And welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the row view using a subclass of NSTableRowView.  You can override drawing in the subclass. or simply set the rows background colour based on the item.

```
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, rowViewForItem item: Any) -> NSTableRowView? {
        switch (item as! NSTreeNode).representedObject {
        case _ as FixtureNode:
            return OSFixtureTableHeaderRowView()
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
```

It took me a long time to figure this out so for anyone interested here is a short clip showing a custom outline view that shows grouped items in a box in the list view. I haven't figured out how to determine when the outline view loses focus to change the selection colours accordingly but for this application it's better that the user can easily see the current selection so there is no immediate requirement but if anyone figures that out let us know.  Happy to post more details if anyone need help. 
[Custom NSOutlineView](https://youtu.be/U7GKvSaPgcc)
[image]

Comment: Thanks Duncan. I'll play with this method.